# How to search a text file for words ending with a and then append r to these words? (Java)

Tags: java

I have a file containing a movie script and I am trying to append 'r' to all the words that end with 'a'. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cubar is a small island country off the Floridar coast.

Comment: Any code will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This is not a free coding service. We expect you to show us what you have tried and explain the difficulties that you encountered while trying to solve your problem. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the String.replaceAll method like this:

```
String script = "a cuba is a bla bla country";
System.out.println(script.replaceAll("a(\\s+)", "ar$1"));
// this gives the result of "ar cubar is ar blar blar country"
```

The first argument for `replaceAll` is a regular expression which means anything ends with `a` and one or more whitespaces. The second argument is the replacement which appends `r` after `a` and keeps the first capturing group which is the whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

We can split this problem into three main stages:

1. Reading from the file
2. Modifying words ending with 'a'
3. Writing back to a file

We can access the file using a FileReader, then read each word using Scanner. An example of how to do this is available on the [Oracle Basic IO tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

To check if each word ends in 'a', we can compare the final character with 'a'. If this is the case, we can append 'r' to this using Java's string concatenation:

```
    if(word.charAt(word.length()-1) == 'a'){
        word = word + 'r';
    }
```

Finally, we can write all of this back to a file, using Java's [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println(script.replaceAll("\\b.*?a\\b", "$0r"));
```

**`\b.*?a\b`** will match boundary word ending with `a`.